# Espacio en blanco generado por el navegador mozilla

Tags: html5, css3, bootstrap-4

tengo un problemita respecto a una maquetación veran se genera un espacio en blanco que solo me pasa con el navegador mozilla, lo cual ocaciona que el menu no se acomode como debe ser ya que este espacio en blanco ocupa un espacio en el menu, Quedo atento a sus sugerencias
[image: Espacio en blanco generado por mozilla]

Comment: Por favor publicá el código de lo que estás haciendo. Como texto, no como una imagen. Estás escribiendo a mano el HTML o se genera en el servidor?

Comment: Hola lo hago en html

Comment: Ya publique el codigo html y css gracias

Answer (score 0):

```
<nav id="nav">
            <ul>
                <li class="user-account">
                    <i class="fas fa-user-circle" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal"></i>
                    <h6>Administrador</h6>
                </li>
                <li class="submenu" id="menu-2-users"> <a href="#">Usuarios</a><!--Menu para responsive-->
                    <ul class="sub-submenu">
                        <li><a href="../modulo_usuarios/agregar_usuario.html">Agregar</a></li>
                        <li><a href="../modulo_usuarios/consultar_usuario.html">Consultar</a></li>
                        <li><a href="../modulo_usuarios/role_funciones.html"> Roles</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="submenu" id="menu-1-users"> <a href="#"><span><i class="fas fa-users"></i></span> Usuarios <span class="span2"><i class="down fas fa-angle-down"></i></span></a>
                    <ul class="sub-submenu">
                        <li><a href="../modulo_usuarios/agregar_usuario.html">Agregar usuario</a></li>
                        <li><a href="../modulo_usuarios/consultar_usuario.html">Consultar usuario</a></li>
                        <li><a href="../modulo_usuarios/role_funciones.html"> Roles & Funciones</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="submenu borde-left" > <a href="#"><span><i class="fas fa-bullhorn"></i></span> Comunicados <span class="span2"><i class="down fas fa-angle-down"></i></span></a>
                    <ul class="sub-submenu">
                        <li><a href="../modulo_pqrs_comunicados/crear_comunicado.html">Crear comunicado</a></li>
                        <li><a href="../modulo_pqrs_comunicados/consultar_comunicado.html">Consultar</a></li>
                        <li><a href="../modulo_pqrs_comunicados/organizar_comunicado.html">Organizar</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="submenu borde-left" > <a href="#"><span><i class="fas fa-calendar-day"></i></span> Eventos <span class="span2"><i class="down fas fa-angle-down"></i></span></a>
                    <ul class="sub-submenu">
                        <li><a href="../modulo_zona_comun/crear_evento.html">Crear evento</a></li>
                        <li><a href="../modulo_zona_comun/consultar_evento.html">Consultar</a></li>
                        <li><a href="../modulo_zona_comun/organizar_evento.html">Organizar</a></li>
                        <li><a href="../modulo_zona_comun/consultar-calendario-eventos.html">Calendario</a></li>
                        <li><a href="../modulo_zona_comun/consultar_inscripciones.html">Inscripciones</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="submenu borde-left" id="menu-2-zonas"> <a href="#">Zonas</a><!--Menu para responsive-->
                    <ul class="sub-submenu">
                        <li><a href="../modulo_zona_comun/crear_zona.html">Crear</a></li>
                        <li><a href="../modulo_zona_comun/consultarzonascomunes.html">Consultar</a></li>
                        <li><a href="../modulo_zona_comun/organizar_zona.html">Organizar</a></li>
                        <li><a href="../modulo_zona_comun/consultar-calendario-reservas.html">Calendario</a></li>
                        <li><a href="../modulo_zona_comun/consultar_reservas.html">Reservas</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="submenu borde-left" class="borde-left" id="menu-1-zonas"><a href="#"><span><i class="fas fa-thumbtack"></i></span> Zonas Comunes <span class="span2"><i class="down fas fa-angle-down"></i></span></a>
                    <ul class="sub-submenu">
                        <li><a href="../modulo_zona_comun/crear_zona.html">Crear zona</a></li>
                        <li><a href="../modulo_zona_comun/consultarzonascomunes.html">Consultar zona</a></li>
                        <li><a href="../modulo_zona_comun/organizar_zona.html">Organizar</a></li>
                        <li><a href="../modulo_zona_comun/consultar-calendario-reservas.html">Calendario de reservas</a></li>
                        <li><a href="../modulo_zona_comun/consultar_reservas.html">Consultar reservas</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="submenu borde-left" id="menu-2-pqrs"><a href="#">PQRS</a><!--Menu para responsive-->
                    <ul class="sub-submenu">
                        <li><a href="../modulo_pqrs_comunicados/pqrs.html">Consultar</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="submenu borde-left" id="menu-1-pqrs"><a href="#"><span><i class="far fa-comment-alt"></i></span> Servicio PQRs <span class="span2"><i class="down fas fa-angle-down"></i></span></a>
                    <ul class="sub-submenu">
                        <li><a href="../modulo_pqrs_comunicados/pqrs.html">Consultar PQRs</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="borde-left"><a href="../modulo_reportes/reportes.html"><span><i class="fas fa-chart-line"></i></span> Reportes</a></li>
                <li class="submenu borde-left"><a href="#"><span><i class="far fa-folder-open"></i></span> Documentación<span class="span2"><i class="down fas fa-angle-down"></i></span></a>
                    <ul class="sub-submenu">
                        <li><a href="#">Fase 1 </a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Fase 2 <span class="span2"><i class="down fas fa-angle-down"></i></span></a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="../documentacion_del_sistema/fase_2/d_actividades.html"> Actividades</a></li>
                                <li><a href="../documentacion_del_sistema/fase_2/d_secuencias.html"> Secuencias</a></li>
                                <li><a href="../documentacion_del_sistema/fase_2/d_comunicacion.html"> Comunicacion</a></li>
                                <li><a href="../documentacion_del_sistema/fase_2/d_flujo_datos.html"> Flujo de datos</a></li>
                                <li><a href="../documentacion_del_sistema/fase_2/d_paquetes.html"> Paquetes</a></li>
                                <li><a href="../documentacion_del_sistema/fase_2/d_er.html"> Entidad-Rel.</a></li>
                                <li><a href="../documentacion_del_sistema/fase_2/d_clases.html"> Clases</a></li>
                                <li><a href="../documentacion_del_sistema/fase_2/c_extendido.html"> Extendido</a></li>
                                <li><a href="../documentacion_del_sistema/fase_2/d_relacional.html"> Relacional</a></li>
                                <li><a href="../documentacion_del_sistema/fase_2/d_procesos.html"> Procesos</a></li>
                                <li><a href="../documentacion_del_sistema/fase_2/caso_uso_español.html"> Caso de uso</a></li>
                                <li><a href="../documentacion_del_sistema/fase_2/caso_uso_ingles.html"> Case of Use</a></li>
                                <li><a href="../documentacion_del_sistema/fase_2/d_estados.html"> Estados</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Fase 3 <span class="span2"><i class="down fas fa-angle-down"></i></span></a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="../documentacion_del_sistema/fase_3/d_despliegue_componente.html"> Despliegue</a></li>
                                <li><a href="../documentacion_del_sistema/fase_3/d_red.html">Infraestructura</a></li>
                                <li><a href="../documentacion_del_sistema/fase_3/modelotrescapas.html">Modelo 3 capas</a></li>
                                <li><a href="../documentacion_del_sistema/fase_3/diagramamysql.html">Modelo relacional</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <div class="logout">
                    <a href="../../../index.html"><span class="span2"><i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i></span>Cerrar Sesión</a>
                </div>
                <div class="idioma">
                    <a href="#"><img src="../../img/country-es.png" alt="" class="country"></a>
                    <a href="inicio_admin_en.html"><img src="../../img/country-us.png" alt="" class="country" style="opacity: 50%;"></a>
                </div>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

Comment: Por favor edita tu publicación y añade el HTML a la pregunta, no publiques cosas de la pregunta en la zona de respuesta por favor.

Answer (score 0):

```
/* --- Estilos para el menu --- */
#menu-2-zonas, #menu-2-users, #menu-2-pqrs, nav .user-account{
    display:none;
}
nav li ul,  nav .idioma, nav .logout, nav span {
    display: none;
}
nav{
    border-bottom: 5px solid #2A6378;
}
nav .borde-left{
    border-left: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.5);
}
nav a {
    color:#FFFFFF;
}
nav a:hover{    
    color:#FFFFFF;
}
nav li {
    line-height: 3.5rem;
    position: relative;
}
nav li ul{
    position: absolute;
}
nav li:hover >ul{
    display:block;
}
nav ul li:hover{
    background: #2A6378;      
}
/* Primer nivel */
nav ul{
    background: rgb(28, 30, 32);
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
nav ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    width:14.28%;
    text-align: center;
    transition: 0.8s all;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    font-size: 18px;
    border-bottom:1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.5);
    z-index: 1000;
}
/* Segundo nivel */
nav ul li ul li{
    width: 100%;
}
nav ul li ul{
    top:100%
}
/* Tercer nivel */
nav ul ul ul{
    right: 100%;
    top:0;
}
/* Boton para menú responsive */
.btn-menu{
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    padding: 22px;
    text-align: center;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    background: #019CDE;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0, 1);
    transform: translateX(100px);
    z-index: 1000;
}
.btn-menu:hover{
    transform: scale(1.2);
    background: #42acfa;
}
/* --- Fin estilos menu --- */
```